# Azure Synapse transaction stuck in queued state

Tags: azure, locking, azure-synapse

We have several tables living in an Azure Synapse DB that we need to truncate as part of a larger pipeline. But, starting very recently, whenever we try to truncate the tables, the transactions are unable to complete and get stuck in an eternal state of suspension.

`sys.dm_pdw_exec_requests` shows these transactions as having a `status` of "Suspended" while `sys.dm_pdw_waits` shows them as being in a `state` of "Queued" with a `priority` of "8". Does anyone know what these values mean? We haven't found any further documentation on them. Any suggestions on particular queries that can be executed within Synapse that could provide more detail about the reason for these suspensions?

The reason all of this matters to us is that we have a pipeline set up in Azure Data Factory that copies data to these tables. This pipeline is set up to first truncate the data in our tables before inserting new data. Because the truncation is eternally suspended, the copy jobs never complete and the pipeline fails.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to repro the issue in my environment where I have multiple tables in Azure Synapse Dedicated pool.

I have run the command `TRUNCATE TABLE <table_name>` and it works fine for me as shown in below image.

[image]

The `select * from sys.dm_pdw_exec_requests` is also showing that my query Completed successfully.

[image]

I have also tied to truncate multiple tables in a single run and that also works fine for me.

[image]

> `sys.dm_pdw_exec_requests` shows these transactions as having a status of "Suspended"

SUSPENDED: It means that the request currently is not active because it is waiting on a resource. The resource can be an I/O for reading a page, A WAIT can be communication on the network, or it is waiting for lock or a latch. It will become active once the task it is waiting for is completed.

> `sys.dm_pdw_waits` shows them as being in a state of "Queued" with a priority of "8"

It means your query is in Queue and will be executed once other queries which are in queue with higher priority will be completed.

To set the priority of your queries, you can **configure workload importance in dedicated SQL pool**. Setting importance in dedicated SQL pool for Azure Synapse allows you to influence the scheduling of queries. **Queries with higher importance will be scheduled to run before queries with lower importance.** To assign importance to queries, you need to create a workload classifier.

Refer [configure workload importance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-how-to-configure-workload-importance) to implement the same.

Comment: Thanks Utkarsh! I will look into adjusting the query importance and the workload classifier. So if the request is suspended because it is waiting for resources, that means that the table itself isn't locked? Does that just mean that there are other queries being run on the Synapse dedicated pool and until those queries finish, we can't run any other queries? I'm just trying to understand if the problem is with the table itself (the one that I'm trying to truncate) or with the dedicated pool.

Comment: Table not need to be locked. Yes, it simply means other queries are in queue and they have higher priority. Once those queries will be completed your next query will run. The problem is in the query priority.

Comment: Got it. Makes sense. I've also been in touch with Azure more and apparently it was related to some index reorganization that was trying to happen in the background. so tables were getting cleaned up, which was blocking the truncate jobs I was trying to run. We ended up solving it by making the truncate jobs run sequentially instead of simultaneously in parallel.